# can jquery check if the class is applied?

Tags: jquery, class, validation

I downloaded a jquery.validatation plugin which is easy to use but I wonder if I can add scripts myself by checking if the class applied...

how this plug-in work is....

eg. if my html code is...

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="required email" />
```

I just put the class="required email" and the jquery validation I linked will check if the email is valid and shows an error message at the side of the textbox if it's not valid but if I want to add let's say changing the bg color of the textbox/put an alert.

Is this possible?

I'm not sure if the class is always applied while the page is running because I don't want to touch the plug-in I downloaded...(it's a bit too complicated for me to know what's going on in the plug-in script)

Comment: I am sorry but i can't get it...

Comment: What plugin are you using?,

Comment: let me see if I can rephrase it more clear....

Comment: If you want to check for a class, you can use `$(element).hasClass(class)`

Comment: you want to colorize the background of the field that didnt pass validation, all you have to do is define a CSS class for that field. For example, some plugins will add an .error class to the fields with the error, so just do something like input.error { background: red; }

Comment: hope it's easier to understand now what I mean :P

Answer (score 1):

**can jquery check if the class is applied?**

Yes, you can check using `hasClass()` method.

for eg.

```
if($('#mydiv').hasClass('foo'))
{
     alert('mydiv has foo clas');
}
else
{
     alert('no foo class found !!');
}
```

for more details go through [**this**](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in your validation-

```
$('#email.required.email')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a custom `CSS Class` for error inputs.

```
$(".selector").validate({
   errorClass: "invalid"
})
```

Define your CSS Class for whatever style you want.

```
input.invalid {
    background-color: red;
}
```

## Update:

The above example works. It is here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bittu4u4ever/d9uHs/1/). And also you can add just CSS as

```
input.error {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: so ".selector" is like all the selector including id, class, element?

Comment: and .validate checks if the selector is applied? if not then an class called .invalid will be created?

Comment: its the form selector. if your form has class `.selector` as `<form class="selector">`. use it to trigger the validation plugin